# Using Pandas query

Tags: pandas

Assigning today’s date to a variable, then using variable inside pandas query to print all rows in column "date" that match the variable.

[image: code]

Prints this:

[image: Prints]

Should print several rows from dataframe where date matches today's date. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: What's the result of `df.head(10).to_dict()`?

Comment: Thank you. df.head returns the whole dataframe, including rows for dates that are not a match for today variable.

Comment: You should add the `[python]` tag/badge.

Comment: `df[df.date.eq(today)]`

Answer (score 0):

You may use `df.query`. During parsing a number of disallowed characters inside the backtick quoted string are replaced by strings that are allowed as a Python identifier.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).